# Coordinate layout using extra space at bottom on scroll

Tags: android, layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using collapsingtoolbar layout with coordinate layout in which when content is more in nested scroll view it works fine but as content is less in nested scroll view it takes extra space from bottom. I tried many answers here but still couldn't find any solution for this. Don't know where i am doing wrong.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_tool_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="#00000000"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:titleEnabled="false">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view_collapse_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/activity_bar_image_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_collapse_toolbar" />

            <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
                android:id="@+id/view_pager_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/indicator_height"
                android:layout_above="@+id/relative_wrap_bar" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grad_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relative_wrap_bar"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relative_wrap_bar"
                android:background="@drawable/grad_fade_layer" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_wrap_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_bar_info"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_very_low"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_check_in"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="60"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_viewpager"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/check_in"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/text_check_in"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="@string/check_ins"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_low" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_males"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="40"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_viewpager"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/males"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/text_males"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="@string/males"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_low" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_females"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="40"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_viewpager"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/females"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/text_females"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="@string/females"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_low" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_rating"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="4.2"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_viewpager"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/rating"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/text_rating"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="@string/rating"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_low" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/text_reviews"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="59"
                            android:textColor="@color/color_viewpager"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/reviews"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/text_reviews"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="@string/reviews"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_low" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:text="Bar Now App"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_toolbar_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_normal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/padding_very_low"
                    android:src="@drawable/fav_icon_empty" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_bar_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorBarDetailMenu"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_tab_selection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_about"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_about"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/about_selected" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_about_triangle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/tip"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_offers"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_offers"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/offers_normal" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_offers_triangle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/tip"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_feeds"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_feeds"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/feeds_normal" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_feeds_triangle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/tip"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_check_ins"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_checkin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/checkin_normal" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_checkin_triangle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/tip"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_go_live"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_go_live"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/go_live_normal" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_go_live_triangle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/tip"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_direction"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_direction"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/directions_normal" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/all_layout_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_about_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_relative_low">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_view_bar_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Located in the heart of Downtown San Jose."
                android:textColor="@color/colorBarInfoTxt"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_contact_details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_view_bar_info"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_high"
                android:text="@string/contact_details"
                android:textColor="@color/colorContactDetails"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_high"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_phone_number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_contact_details"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_very_low"
                android:text="Phone:"
                android:textColor="@color/colorContactDetails"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_phone_number_api"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt_phone_number"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt_phone_number"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_very_low"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt_phone_number"
                android:text="+1 408-915-2337"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBarInfoTxt"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/social_connects"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_phone_number"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_low"
                android:text="@string/social_connects"
                android:textColor="@color/colorContactDetails"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relative_social_connect"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/social_connects"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_very_low">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_facebook_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_twitter_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_low"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_facebook_icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_instagram_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_low"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_twitter_icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/instagram" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_website_icon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_low"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_instagram_icon"
                    android:src="@drawable/website" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bar_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative_social_connect"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_high"
                android:text="@string/address"
                android:textColor="@color/colorContactDetails"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_high"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_bar_address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bar_address"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_very_low"
                android:text="Agicent Technologies"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBarInfoTxt"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_bar_address"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_high"
                android:text="@string/timing"
                android:textColor="@color/colorContactDetails"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_high"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_timing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/timings"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_very_low"
                android:text="Sun-Wed: 11:30 am to 11:30 pm"
                android:textColor="@color/colorContactDetails"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_normal" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/map_relative"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt_timing"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_low"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_high">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/google_map_frag_bar_info"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/map_height_on_business_layout" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Try to give layout_height="wrap_content" to nestedscrollview if it helps.

Comment: @Drv i have already tried it.